# Row based time difference based on condition for Analytics

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have the following data in a table called `TABLE`:

**EDIT**: Added another couple rows with `Characterid: 26052013030101`, which was missed.

```
    /------------------------------------------------------------------------\
    |      CharacterID     |     EVENTTYPE     |        TRIGGERTIME          |
    |----------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------|
    |    11052016190101    |    START          |   2017-06-01 13:35:38.000   |
    |    11052016190101    |    END            |   2017-01-06 08:05:18.620   |
    |    01012016170101    |    START          |   2017-06-01 13:33:18.000   |
    |    01012016170101    |    Player Left    |   2017-06-01 13:35:21.000   |
    |    01012016170101    |    END            |   2017-06-01 13:38:22.000   |
    |    26052013030101    |    START          |   2017-06-01 13:35:39.000   |
    |    26052013030101    |    RESET          |   2017-06-01 13:35:50.000   |
    \------------------------------------------------------------------------/
```

I have written this query to to get the time difference based on `START` and `END` values of `EVENTTYPE`:

```
SELECT
    cp_start.characterid,
    MAX(cp_start.triggertime) AS start_time,
    cp_end.triggertime AS end_time,
    datediff(second, MAX(cp_start.triggertime), cp_end.triggertime)
FROM
    TABLE AS cp_start
INNER JOIN
    TABLE AS cp_end ON (
        cp_start.CharacterID= cp_end.CharacterID
    AND
        cp_end.triggertime > cp_start.triggertime)
WHERE cp_start.eventtype = 'START'
AND cp_end.eventtype = 'END'
GROUP BY cp_start.characterid, cp_Start.TriggerTime, cp_end.TriggerTime
```

However, what we want is to get the time difference for the above condition - i.e. `START` and `END` - and if there is any other event between `START` and `END` then we need to skip that particular `CharacterID`.

In the above example see `CharacterID = 01012016170101`, there is a row with `EVENTTYPE='Player Left'` row between the rows with `START` and `END` values for `EVENTTYPE` which ***need to be skipped or not to be considered***.

**EDIT**: In the above, characterid = 26052013030101, has only START but no END. It has RESET, meaning we should not consider this value while displaying the result.
END OF EDIT

How do we achieve this?

Secondly, Is there any easy method to achieve this in POWERBI and display the count and time difference?

Comment: Could the same `CharacterId` "START" and "END" multiple times? Or will there only ever be one record per `CharacterId` with each value of `EVENTTYPE` of "START" and "END"?

Comment: Also, is there a typo in your example data, or should there really be 3 distinct `CharacterId` values? Seems like maybe the one shown as `01012013010101` should actually be `01012016170101` like the two rows below it?

Comment: And is it right that the "END" date for `CharacterId=11052016190101` is an earlier date than the "START" date for that same `CharacterId`? Or are these DateTime values in yyyy-dd-mm format or something?

Comment: Expected/desired output data for the example input data you've provided would be useful, but I've attempted to answer below based on some assumptions.

Comment: @3N1GM4 the CharacterID will be one for each start and end

Comment: @3N1GM4 I have fixed the character ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find every `START` record regardless of how many times a CharacterID starts a session and then finds the following `END` record:

```
declare @t table(CharacterID bigint,EVENTTYPE nvarchar(100),TRIGGERTIME datetime);
insert into @t values
 (11052016190101,'START','2017-01-01 13:35:38.000')
,(11052016190101,'END','2017-01-06 08:05:18.620')
,(01012013010101,'START','2017-06-01 13:33:18.000')
,(01012013010101,'Player Left','2017-06-01 13:35:21.000')
,(01012013010101,'END','2017-06-01 13:38:22.000')
,(01012013010101,'START','2017-07-01 13:33:18.000')
,(01012013010101,'Player Left','2017-07-01 13:35:21.000')
,(01012013010101,'END','2017-07-01 13:38:22.000');

with Starts as
(
    select CharacterID
            ,EVENTTYPE
            ,TRIGGERTIME
    from @t
    where EVENTTYPE = 'START'
)
select s.CharacterID
        ,s.TRIGGERTIME as StartTime
        ,e.TRIGGERTIME as EndTime
from Starts s
    outer apply (select top 1 TRIGGERTIME
                    from @t
                    where CharacterID = s.CharacterID
                        and TRIGGERTIME > s.TRIGGERTIME
                        and EVENTTYPE = 'END'
                    order by TRIGGERTIME
                ) e
order by CharacterID
        ,StartTime;
```

I have slightly changed your test data so that it actually makes sense, but using the data in the script above, the output is as follows:

```
CharacterID    | StartTime               | EndTime
---------------+-------------------------+------------------------
1012013010101  | 2017-06-01 13:33:18.000 | 2017-06-01 13:38:22.000
1012013010101  | 2017-07-01 13:33:18.000 | 2017-07-01 13:38:22.000
11052016190101 | 2017-01-01 13:35:38.000 | 2017-01-06 08:05:18.620
```

Comment: the solution looks good but, for some reason, if there is "START" but no "END" for the same characterid, then the above query doesn't provide best of result.

Comment: If the most recent `START` has no `END` you get a `null` value `EndTime`, which you can substitute to any value you like with the `isnull` function or exclude in your `where`.  If you have multiple `START` records without an `END` record for the same `CharacterID`, surely you have data issues that need resolving before doing this analysis?

Answer (score 1):

Based on some assumptions:

- You only ever have one record per `CharacterId` for each of the two relevant `EVENTTYPE` values ("START" and "END")
- Any record with an `EVENTTYPE` value of "END" will always have a later datetime value in `TRIGGERTIME` than the record for the same `CharacterId` with an `EVENTTYPE` of "START".

You could use something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    c.CharacterId,
    start.TRIGGERTIME AS StartTime,
    [end].TRIGGERTIME AS EndTime,
    DATEDIFF(s, start.TRIGGERTIME, [end].TRIGGERTIME) AS [TimeDiff(seconds)]
FROM [TABLE] c
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TRIGGERTIME
    FROM [TABLE] s
    WHERE s.CharacterId = c.CharacterId
    AND s.EVENTTYPE = 'START'
) start
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TRIGGERTIME
    FROM [TABLE] e
    WHERE e.CharacterId = c.CharacterId
    AND e.EVENTTYPE = 'END'
) [end]
```

If you want to present the time difference in a different way than just the number of seconds, that can be handled separately and there are lots of other questions on SO which deal with this.

You could equally move the `OUTER APPLY`s into subqueries in the `SELECT` clause, but this way make the logic a little easier to follow IMHO.