# Count in-between rows from same column values

Tags: sql, sql-server

In Microsoft SQL server, how to count in-between rows based on the values from the same column.

### Example

```
/-----------------------------------------\
| ID ---------- Event -------- UserID ----|
| 1 ----------- START -------- 000001 ----|
| 2 ----------- START -------- 000002 ----|
| 3 ----------- END   -------- 000001 ----|
| 4 ----------- PL    -------- 000002 ----|
| 5 ----------- END   -------- 000002 ----|
\-----------------------------------------/
```

Consider for `UserID` 000002, which has 3 rows present and the ID are 2, 4 & 5.
Based on the query from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588409/row-based-time-difference-based-on-condition-for-analytics) I am able to get the `START` and `END` time, but how to get the **count of rows** between `START` and `END` for each `USERID`

**Expected Result**

```
/-------------------------------------------------------\
| UserID ------------------------- Row Count -----------|
| 000001 ------------------------- 2         -----------|
| 000002 ------------------------- 3         -----------|
\-------------------------------------------------------/
```

Comment: Not simple, please read

Comment: @aioracle:-  your question is not clear... because you told that "how to get the count of rows between START and END for each USERID" & also your Expected Result also differ..please clear what you want..?

Comment: Between start and end means that there should be some way to order the rows by. What version of sql server are you working with?

Comment: Can there be more than one start for a user? More than one end? Records before start? Records after end? If so, what to do in these cases?

Comment: As you are talking of rows *between* others, I suppose that ID is not just some technical ID here to identify records, but you also consider a record with a small ID *previous* to a record with a higher ID. Is this correct?

Comment: The scenario is not clear. **(1)** Is there only a single START-END per UserId? **(2)** Does a START always have an END? **(3)** Is START always the first EVENT and END is the last event per UserID?

Comment: Also - what is your SQL Server version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario is not well defined and you can see it in the varying complexity of the solutions.

This will handle the simple use-case.

```
select      UserID
           ,count(*)    as cnt
from        mytable
```

This will handle the complex use-case.

```
select      UserID
           ,min(ID)     as from_ID
           ,max(ID)     as to_ID
           ,count(*)    as events

from       (select      UserID,ID,Event
                       ,    count(case when Event in ('START','END') then 1 end) over 
                            (
                                partition by    UserID 
                                order by        Id 
                                rows            unbounded preceding
                            )   
                        -   case when Event = 'END' then 1 else 0 end   as group_seq

            from        mytable
            ) t

group by    UserID
           ,group_seq

having      min(case when Event = 'START' then 1 end) = 1

order by    UserID
           ,from_id
```

Comment: the solution for complex use-case has provided me with solution, however, in case I want to know what is the event values between START and END, how can I do it?

Comment: How does the result you are expecting to see looks like?

Comment: P.s. If you'll run only the inner query you'll see that each group of events (START to END) has its own `group_seq`

Comment: In case I want to display like 
/--------------------------------------------------------------------------\
| UserID -------- Row Count ------- valuebetweenS_E ----- |
| 000001 -------- 2         -----------    NULL --------------------- |
| 000002 -------- 3         -----------    PL --------------------------|
\--------------------------------------------------------------------------/

Comment: It depends on how my customer wants to view the data. I am just preparing to "In case" if they want.

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT USERID
  , sum(CASE WHEN MainT.ID BETWEEN StartT.ID AND EndT.ID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RowCount
FROM Table1 AS MainT
  INNER JOIN Table1 AS StartT 
    ON MainT.USERID = StartT.USERID AND StartT.event = 'START'
  INNER JOIN Table1 AS EndT 
    ON MainT.USERID = EndT.USERID AND EndT.event = 'END'
GROUP BY USERID`

This should produce the desired output, with the following assumptions:

- ID is (auto) incrementing, so a user's START event has the lowest ID. Hopefully a timestamp is available in the real data.
- Each relevant user has a one START and zero or one END events, but users that start or end outside the dataset are not included.

In response to the comment:

Normally, you cannot show "the" value for a field that's not being grouped by, as there might be multiple values in play. That means you need to tell SQL server how to handle the values with some kind of aggregate function.

If you are certain there's only one possible value per group, you can cheat a bit and take min(event) or max(event). That gives you the first or last value **alphabetically** that appears in the group. This is risky though and likely to cause issues if you later include more events in that table.

You can split the count by event type if there are only a few:

`sum(CASE WHEN **MainT.event ='EventA' AND** MainT.ID BETWEEN StartT.ID AND EndT.ID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EventACount,
 sum(CASE WHEN **MainT.event ='EventB' AND** MainT.ID BETWEEN StartT.ID AND EndT.ID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EventBCount,`

Finally, you could use some kind of list aggregation, concatenating all event types appearing in the group. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver) goes into more detail on that.

Comment: Second join should be a left join under these assumptions.

Comment: I'm excluding the users that don't have an END record yet, hence the inner join. If a "count up to now" is desired, it should be a left join and the case should read "CASE WHEN MainT.ID BETWEEN StartT.ID AND ISNULL(EndT.ID,MaintT.ID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

Comment: I see. I think this question needs some more explanations. Your answer seems good to me. +1

Comment: @Cyrus the solution works as expected. Is there any possibility to display the event which is between START and END in another column?

Comment: @Cyrus, I cannot mark 2 answers. Your solution also works for me.

Comment: @aioracle No problem, but thanks for the comment, that way other readers know this works too.