# Get in-between cell value from same column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I previously asked how to get the `count of in-between rows from same column values` which can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42018981/count-in-between-rows-from-same-column-values). The solutions provided works perfectly fine, but now I need additional extra column to get ***`all`*** values between `START` and `END`.

**Sample Table**

```
/-----------------------------------------\
| ID ---------- Event -------- UserID ----|
| 1 ----------- START -------- 000001 ----|
| 2 ----------- START -------- 000002 ----|
| 3 ----------- END   -------- 000001 ----|
| 4 ----------- PL    -------- 000002 ----|
| 5 ----------- END   -------- 000002 ----|
\-----------------------------------------/
```

**Desired output**

```
/---------------------------------------------------------\
| UserID ----------- Row Count ----------- rowbetweenvalue|
| 000001 ----------- 2         ----------- NULL           |
| 000002 ----------- 3         ----------- PL             |
\---------------------------------------------------------/
```

Comment: What do you plan to show for `rowbetweenvalue` in case there is _more_ than one record in between two markers?

Comment: If I can show like this PL ,  RC , ZZ what would be good. Generally, I will have only one record in between two markers, but at a very cases I might get more than one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it, based on the solution provided by Dudu Markovitz, is this:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    id int,
    event varchar(5),
    UserId char(6)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1, 'START', '000001'),
(2, 'START', '000002'),
(3, 'END', '000001'),
(4, 'PL', '000002'),
(5, 'ZZ', '000002'),
(6, 'END', '000002')
```

Encapsulate Dudu's answer into a cte

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    select      UserID
               ,min(ID)     as from_ID
               ,max(ID)     as to_ID
               ,count(*)    as events

    from       (select      UserID,ID,Event
                           ,    count(case when Event in ('START','END') then 1 end) over 
                                (
                                    partition by    UserID 
                                    order by        Id 
                                    rows            unbounded preceding
                                )   
                            -   case when Event = 'END' then 1 else 0 end   as group_seq

                from        @T
                ) t

    group by    UserID
               ,group_seq

    having      min(case when Event = 'START' then 1 end) = 1
)
```

The query:

```
SELECT  UserId,
        From_Id,
        To_Id,
        Events As eventCount,
        STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ',' + event
            FROM @T
            WHERE UserId = cte.UserId 
            AND Id > from_ID
            AND Id < to_ID
            FOR XML PATH('')
        )
        , 1, 1, '') As events
FROM CTE    
ORDER BY UserID ,from_id
```

Results:

```
UserId  From_Id To_Id   eventCount  events
000001  1       3       2           NULL
000002  2       6       4           PL,ZZ
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample:

```
WITH sample_table(ID,Event,UserID)AS(
    SELECT 1,'START','000001' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'START','000002' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'END','000001' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,'PL','000002' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5,'RC','000002' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6,'END','000002'
)
SELECT t1.UserID,2+ISNULL(LEN(r.v)-LEN(REPLACE(r.v,',','')),0) AS [Row Count],STUFF(r.v,1,1,'') AS rowbetweenvalue
FROM sample_table AS t1
CROSS APPLY(SELECT top 1 ID AS ENDID FROM sample_table AS tt WHERE tt.UserID=t1.UserID AND tt.ID>t1.ID AND tt.Event='END' ORDER BY ID) c
CROSS APPLY(SELECT ','+st.Event FROM sample_table AS st WHERE st.UserID=t1.UserID AND st.ID>t1.ID AND st.ID<c.ENDID FOR XML PATH('')) AS r(v)
WHERE t1.Event='START'
```

```
UserID Row Count            rowbetweenvalue
------ -------------------- ------------------------
000001 2                    NULL
000002 4                    PL,RC
```